# What does the tty tag mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

What does the tag [tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tty) mean? It seems to be used sometimes synonymously with [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal), sometimes synonymously with [console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console), even sometimes to mean [command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line). Does it have a meaning of its own? Should we retag it away?

Comment: It can have a meaning of its own. If someone bothers to make a wiki description for it! Other than that, I don't even see much difference between [console] and [terminal].

Answer (score 5):

*A terminal is at the end of an electric wire, a shell is the home of a turtle, tty is a strange abbreviation and a console is [[…](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/28489)]* :-)

Believe it, might, should keep on living, but with a decent wiki defining it. It could also perhaps be an idea to have a *"see also: terminal, console, shell ..."* and, in danger of perhaps breaking some wiki-convention, even a link to the above quoted answer/question or the like. (It is perhaps not possible in the excerpt / short-tag.)

In my experience, at least for Linux etc. users, where one usually have tty1-7 trough <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, and the familiar. (as in):

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------- - -  -
|
| Welcome to Linux 3.10-rc1 (tty1)
|
| SERV login: _
|
. ...
| 
| SERV login: john
| Password:
| Linux 3.10-rc1
| Last login: May 14 05:32:16 +0200 2013 on tty1.
| You have new mail.
|
| Blore's Razor:
|        Given a choice between two theories, take the one which is funnier.
|
| SERV@john: ~$
```

the light use of the word is for these access points to the system. Usually when explicitly referring to a non-X environment – as in: not terminal-emulator.
It kind of becomes a short-cut to express something in a way that hopefully is quickly recognized. I.e. *"When on tty4 …"*, *"X went nuclear so I logged into another TTY …"*, etc.

Whilst *terminal* often, but not always, is used to express virtual emulators in a GUI environment. And *console* get a mixed use between them all. I seldom see anyone use the phrasing tty-window, but it happens.

I do not know how the tags affect the underlying logic of e.g. search beyond direct specification. But at least for those of us frequently using `"[some_tag] search term"` the use of `tty` would perhaps have it's purpose.

<sup>Though, as a side point, I rarely use it here, but mostly on Stackoverflow for `[C]`, `[asm]` etc. where it definitively is a saver.</sup>

---

Point of i all being how to express the tag-wiki in a way best served. Giving the possibility to re-tag if far off, and also being a source of information thus learning.

---

*A short undecided discussion with myself and you all.*

So; *what does the tty tag mean*? Quickly realizing that this did *not* became an answer, I'll leave it in hope it might give some input on how and what to do. If not I can delete.

Answer (score -1):

[tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tty)s are special files (i. e. an interface provided by kernel) for terminal devices, and things directly related to it (`stty`, line vs character mode, etc.).

[console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console) is an actual set of devices and stuff specific to it (virtual consoles, `loadkeys`, `setfont`, framebuffer vs VGA, raw vs cooked keyboard in Linux, etc.)

Ī̲ don’t know whether a useful denotation for [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) can be defined under current conditions of this site. It is so broadly used that ceased to be selective; seemingly for anything related to TUI (mostly run within emulators by modern users). Whereas specific tags ([terminal-emulator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal-emulator), [pty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pty)) are underpopulated and neglected.